# AngularJS locationProvider Routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to Angular and I'm currently building a few test/dummy apps to get my head around the way it works and become more-familiar with SPA's in Angular. However, I've stumbled into an issue when I start adding routes to my application and loading the content via `ng-view`

$locationProvider doesn't seem to be working correctly because if I go to `localhost/sdfsdf` then I get cannot GET `/sdfsdf` when in reality the page should be redirecting to `/cocktails`.

**routes.js**

```
var cocktailApp = angular.module('cocktailApp', ['ngRoute', 'cocktailControllers']);

cocktailApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        .when('/cocktails', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/cocktail-list.html',
            controller: 'cocktailsController'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/cocktails'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5mode(true);

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular only recognizes anchor URL syntax for URLs pasted directly on the browser. So you have to you try `http://localhost/#/sdfsdf` instead to make your routing work. Please note that anchor syntax `/#` was added in previous URL.

Comment: I still get cannot GET

Comment: no way... I tried on my local it produces the expected result